# div's are not in the same width when its on column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried to create a 3 div container with `max-width 400px;` after I changed the direction to `flex-direction: column;` I lost the width of my container.

(After changing the flex-direction to column my containers are not in the same order)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAfhQ.png)

as shown in the image, the flex row will make the boxes allocated correctly and if I switched to column, the containers are not taking the defined `max-width 400px;`.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Sono", sans-serif;
}

.pricing-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.pricing-plan {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: rgb(245, 241, 241);
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius:5px ;
}

.plan-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

.plan-price {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight:800;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.plan-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  border: 0px white;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .pricing-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flexbox Pricing Table</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sono:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="pricing-container">
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Normal</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$9/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li>10GB Storage</li>
          <li> 1 User</li>
          <li> Support</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li>50GB Storage</li>
          <li>5 Users</li>
          <li> Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing-plan">
        <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
        <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
        <ul class="plan-features">
          <li> 100GB Storage</li>
          <li> 10 Users</li>
          <li> 24/7 Support</li>
        </ul>
        <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's the combination with `align-items: center;`, that makes the items shrink. You should give them an actual width (not just a min-width), and add `flex-shrink: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS:

```
.pricing-container > div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

This will stretch the width of all flex items to 100% of the parent container if that is less than 300px wide or - if the parent is wider than 300px, make them 300px wide, as you defined with `max-width: 300px;`

```css
body {
  font-family: "Sono", sans-serif;
}

.pricing-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.pricing-container > div {
  width: 100%;
}
.pricing-plan {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: rgb(245, 241, 241);
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.plan-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

.plan-price {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.plan-button {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 94, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: white;
  border: 0px white;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .pricing-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Flexbox Pricing Table</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sono:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pricing-container">
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Normal</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$9/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>10GB Storage</li>
        <li> 1 User</li>
        <li> Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Standard</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$19.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li>50GB Storage</li>
        <li>5 Users</li>
        <li> Phone &amp; Email Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <div class="pricing-plan">
      <div class="plan-title">Premium</div>
      <div class="plan-price">$49.99/month</div>
      <ul class="plan-features">
        <li> 100GB Storage</li>
        <li> 10 Users</li>
        <li> 24/7 Support</li>
      </ul>
      <button class="plan-button">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set a specific width in the media query, like width: 100%; for the .pricing-plan class.
thus all plans have the same width in the column layout, which fill the width of their container.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .pricing-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .pricing-plan {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

`.container { max-width: 400px; }`

Comment: Yes but not find any change